# Angular - check which statement is true and create a variable based on that

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three buttons by which I filter, articles, by latest articles, and articles by popularity as well as the ones which only have one video. I am also adding I am also adding a bullet point to the active button:

```
  <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('siste')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletpointSiste"></i> Siste
  </a>
  <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('video')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletpointVideo"></i> Video
  </a>
  <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter()"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletpointPopular"></i> Populært
  </a>
```

In the controller I check which button was clicked like this, set the clicked button bullet point to true, and then refresh the view by calling the function `doRefresh`:

```
$scope.articleFilter = function(button) {
if (button == "siste"){
  $scope.bulletpointSiste = true;
  $scope.bulletpointPopular = false;
  $scope.bulletpointVideo = false;
  $scope.articleType = 'all';
}
else if (button == "video"){
  $scope.bulletpointSiste = false;
  $scope.bulletpointPopular = false;
  $scope.bulletpointVideo = true;
  $scope.articleType = 'video';
}
else {
  $scope.bulletpointVideo = false;
  $scope.bulletpointSiste = false;
  $scope.bulletpointPopular = true;
  $scope.articleType = 'popular';
}

$scope.doRefresh();
```

};

Function `doRefresh` checks which bullet point is true, and sets the var `articleType` to  a correct filter type, which I then use to call the right service function. Now I need to add another filter to this, so I need to change the logic. I am not sure what is the most elegant way to do this, I could add another `else if` statement to the `articleFilter` function:

```
    $scope.doRefresh = function (){
    var articleType = $scope.articleType ? $scope.articleType : 'all';

    ArticleService[articleType]().$promise.then(function(data){
       $scope.articles = data;
    }).finally(function() {
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });
  };
```

I am wondering if there is some more elegant way of setting the correct `bullet point` to `true`:

```
if (button == "siste"){
      $scope.bulletpointSiste = true;
      $scope.bulletpointPopular = false;
      $scope.bulletpointVideo = false;
      $scope.articleType = 'all';
    }
    else if (button == "video"){
      $scope.bulletpointSiste = false;
      $scope.bulletpointPopular = false;
      $scope.bulletpointVideo = true;
      $scope.articleType = 'video';
    }
    else {
      $scope.bulletpointVideo = false;
      $scope.bulletpointSiste = false;
      $scope.bulletpointPopular = true;
      $scope.articleType = 'popular';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there will be always only one bullet visible, what about this?

```
<a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('all')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="showBulletPoint('all')"></i> Siste
  </a>
  <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('video')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="showBulletPoint('video')"></i> Video
  </a>
  <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('popular')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="showBulletPoint('popular')"></i> Populært
  </a>
```

--

```
$scope.articleFilter = function(button) {
    $scope.articleType = button;
}

$scope.showBulletPoint = function(which) {
    return $scope.articleType == which;
}
```

Remember to define a default `articleType`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use only one variable for bulletPoint:

```
$scope.articleFilter = function(button) { 
    $scope.bulletPoint = button;

    // articleType should be all when 'siste', so a bit different...
    if(button == 'siste') $scope.articleType = 'all';
    else $scope.articleType = button;
}
```

And you can change your ng-show condition in HTML:

```
<a ng-click="articleFilter('siste')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletPoint == 'siste'"></i> Siste</a>
<a ng-click="articleFilter('video')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletPoint == 'video'"></i> Video</a>
<a ng-click="articleFilter('popular')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletPoint == 'popular'"></i> Popular</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use so many conditions you can simply create an array of items for the nav with name and a unique value.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    // Holds the active state
    $scope.active = "all";
    
    $scope.filter = [
      { n: "Siste", v: "all"},
      { n: "Video", v: "video"},
      { n: "Popular", v: "popular"}
    ];
  
    $scope.articleFilter = function(typ){
      // Update state

      $scope.active = typ;
      console.log(typ);

      // call service
    }
  
}
```

```css
a > i{
  display: none;
}

a.active > i{
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
 <a ng-repeat="f in filter track by $index"
    ng-class="{'active': f.v == active}"
    ng-click="articleFilter(f.v)"
    href>
    <i>+</i> {{f.n}}
  </a>
  
</div>
  
</body>
```